# use temporary Record ID during transaction

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have record A in database.

In a transaction I want to do the following :

- Create a record B
- link `parent` property of A to B : `A.parent = B.@rid`

Problem is, during a transaction, I get a temporary negative record id.
So `@rid` has a negative position id.
How can I use it to set the link *in the same transaction* ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The negative RID means that is temporary.
When the transaction is committed a real RID will be assigned, after the commit the RID is changed and it's updated in the object.

Here the [doc](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Commit.html) at the end of the page you can see how transactions works

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) are you saying there is no way I can do that in a single transaction ?

Comment: I don't think so, sorry